# Keep set members sorted in Redis

Tags: nosql, redis, instant-messaging

I'm coding an IM system.

I'm using Redis and JSON to store the data. I have a Redis Set with the conversation IDs. When I retrieve them, I would like to get the list sorted by the timestamp of the messages:

```
conversation 9  -> last message timestamp: 1390300000
conversation 12 -> last message timestamp: 1390200000
conversation 7  -> last message timestamp: 1390100000
```

I have a Set with the conversations where each user participates (**user1337:conversations**) and a List with the JSON-encoded messages of each conversation (**conversation1234:messages**).

I guess there is no need for tricks, so it can be done natively with Redis. How would you manage to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a [*Sorted Set*](http://redis.io/topics/data-types) is exactly what you need.

You would set the *timestamp* of each conversation as its score (see [`ZADD`](http://redis.io/commands/zadd)) and then you can retrieve them ordered, using commands like [`ZRANGE`](http://redis.io/commands/zrange), [`ZRANGEBYSCORE`](http://redis.io/commands/zrangebyscore), [`ZREVRANGE`](http://redis.io/commands/zrevrange) and [`ZREVRANGEBYSCORE`](http://redis.io/commands/zrevrangebyscore).

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried Sorted Sets before, but I didn't catch on setting the timestamp directly.

Comment: @OrioldelRio Sounds like the perfect case for a sorted set and it's great that Redis has them built-in :)